# Determining if a request came from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, encryption, verification, public-key-encryption

I have an iPhone app that communicates with a server (both of which I own and wrote the code for). I need to way to determine if a request on my server came from an iPhone (or any mobile device running the app I wrote for that matter). Basically, I only want to allow apps that I wrote to communicate with the server and need a way to verify that. Since I'm writing the apps, I can modify the headers and what not any way I need to.

I read up a little on Public Key Encryption, but I don't think it'd work. If I sent some sort of secret hashed word in my headers to verify it, couldn't some outside party simply get those headers and use the same ones in their request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a checksum. Let's say that you have something like:
date
subject

and calculate the checksum by using, let's say MD5 of (date + "string" + subject),
and you calculate the MD5 in the very same way on the server. If they match, they are from the mobile client.

This will work until someone figures out your algorithm.

Comment: Hmm, that could work. The date would have to be accurate only to the day or so though otherwise they'd never match because you don't know how long the request is going to take.

Comment: Don't forget you may have to take into account different time-zones too which may give different days. Probalby best to use UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your server send a message to your app that contains a random code. This message and code changes every time it is sent.

Your app then does some kind of algorithm on that message to "encrypt" it and send it back to the server and the server can then check it. That way there's nothing to intercept and use without knowing your "encryption".

Of course, they could intercept the message from each direction and then work out your algorithm, but if you make it sufficiently difficult, then that would be a while.

Comment: This is a valid way of going about it, but the requests come in from the apps. To do it this way, I'd have to have the app request the code, do something with the response, and then make yet another request to the server which is probably a lot of unnecessary communication. This would probably be best if I needed it to be more secure than @Zyberzero's response, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use HTTP Basic authentication, unless you needed something more secure.

Comment: Because of what I'm trying to do, it's a tad more complicated than that. All requests authenticate the same way, but I also need to determine where the request is coming from if that makes sense.